# The slider won't repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that this slide still plays and don't stop. Like an automatic loop.  So what is the best code to do that? If you want to edit it, here's the[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkfp5we3/)

Here's the JS code:

```
var s = 0,
    t = 2000;
$(document).on('ready', slide);

function slide() {
    var speed = setTimeout(slider, t, );
}

function slider() {
    s++;
    var sld = $('#slider li'),
        imgs = sld.length;
    if (s == imgs) {
        s = 0;
    }
    sld.eq(s - 1).animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, t, function() {
        sld.eq(s).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, t, function() {
            speed = setTimeout(slider, t);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: tried it, but it still won't repeat

Comment: @JohnCena, your code lacks the logic to **reset** the board. Your setTimeout works well, as you can see.

Comment: So, @JohnCena, you want it to keep on loading after 4? Basically load 5, then 6, then 7, and so on?

Comment: @Snorlax, no, after it loaded 4, it needs to go back to 1 and so on.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not resetting 's' variable. You might think that you are doing that, but you don't have access to that variable from inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
var s = 1, t = 3000;
$(document).on('ready', slider);

function slider(){
    var sld  = $('#slider li'),
        imgs = sld.length;
    if(s == imgs){
        $('#slider li').css('left', '');
        s = 1;
    }
    sld.eq(s).animate({'left': '0px'}, t, function(){
        setTimeout(slider, 1000);
    });
    s++;
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/4e3w5556/2/) for you.

Comment: 1. Does this run smooth to you? No. 2. Does it run like he made it? No. 3. You can't just edit someone's script like that.

Comment: @Snorlax 1. Yes, a bit faster than his though, change `t` to be higher. 2. It runs like he made it and resets to "1" after "4". 3. I think the purpose of stackoverflow is to edit people's scipts to make them work.

Comment: Exactly @Arg0n , this works fine for me! The only problem is that the time between the images are to fast. And can anyone tell me why this post got downvoted to -4???

Comment: I updated `t` to be set to 3000, looks more like yours.

Comment: What i mean is the time before the next image slides needs to be longer, if you know what I mean?

Comment: @JohnCena Updated with `setTimeout` in `callback`

Comment: @Snorlax, "You can't just edit someone's script like that", what is that supposed to mean??

Comment: @Arg0n Thank you! You're my hero for today! :) I'm only 17 and don't know that much about js, but I've learned from you, thank you :)

Comment: @JohnCena No problem, please upvote and mark as accepted answer. It would be sad to see solution stuck at -1 :D

Comment: @Arg0n: Try loading John Cena's and yours at the same time. You can CLEARLY tell the difference between yours and his. Yours start off immediately. When it reaches 4, it basically says "Nope starting all over" and goes from 4 to 1 within a blink. -1 because it's so different than what John Cena made.

Comment: This solved his problem, so it can't be that far off. Plus the problem was that it did not repeat, i fixed that.